# MongoDB, array field of objects with incremental property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I understand the question is a bit confusing. Bear with me,

Let's say I have a Class document which contains Students property as array. Now these students should have an incremental Id but I am not sure how to do that when there are concurrent <s>inserts</s> push queries to the document.

Example:

let's say class is my document in db.

```
var class = {
   'students':[{
      'name': 'Bob'
       'id' :1
   }]
}
```

now if I am to <s>insert</s> push the student Sally (`{'name': 'Sally'}`) to `class.students` I would like her to get 2 as id.

I could query to get the latest id in the db and increment that by one and use it as Sally's id.

However, I don't know what happens when two different requests were made concurrently and one of them tries to <s>insert</s> push Sally and the other Jack. How can I make sure Sally and Jack doesn't get the same id?

A note; I don't want to rely on the array index for id field.

Comment: Use a GUID or  UUID these are most likely to be unique on every creation.

Comment: Right, but I also want the id to be readable. I would like to refer bob as "Student-1" not "Student-asfasf29-dajs-doajsdo2ke-12".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with help of counter collection

1.Insert into the counters collection, the initial value for the studentId:

```
db.counters.insert(
   {
      _id: "studentId",
      seq: 0
   }
)
```

2. Create a getNextSequence function that accepts a name of the sequence. The function uses the findAndModify() method to **atomically** increment the seq value and return this new value

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );

   return ret.seq;
}
```

As findAndModify is atomic operation, getNextSequence() will always return next value, even in case of the concurrent requests.

3.Use this getNextSequence() function during insert/push

```
//let's assume you already have a 'student' variable that represents a student doc
student['id'] = getNextSequence("studentId");
db.classes.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $addToSet: { students: student  } }
)
```

More details about an auto-incrementing sequence field could be found in the [corresponding tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) on MongoDb website.